# SpecialCells in Excel JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

In VBA Excel, I can choose cells based if they have formulas or values.

```
Sub ColorCells()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 1)
End Sub
```

Also, I can specify if I want to get only text values, numbers, errors and/or booleans.

How can I do that with Excel JavaScript API? It is a pretty important method. Currently, I'm looping all the worksheet's used range rectangle to get the values, and my loops spend a lot of time in blank cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news ! SpecialCells functionality is in beta now! We now support range areas and also specialCells please give it a try and send us feedback. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-multiple-ranges

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the functionality that you've described is currently available in the Excel JavaScript API. If you'd like to add this feature request to [Office Developer Platform UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/), other users can vote on it there, enabling the Office PM team to get a sense for overall priority/demand as they plan for future enhancements to the API.

Comment: Yes, it is not supported. I've created a link for this idea here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32646361-special-cells-method

Comment: Please see my latest: this is now in beta !